# QCombobox & QListWidget - Check Content

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, qcombobox, qlistwidget

I want to ask if there is a way to check if an item is in a QListWidget or in a QComboBox.
With that I want to make sure that every item is unique in the QListWidget or in the QCombobox.
I want something in that way if it is possible:

```py
   for i in range(0, len(LISTE), 1):
       if LISTE[i] in self.liste:
          return
       else:
          self.liste.addItem(LISTE[i])
```

Comment: Well if you used the QListWidget or QComboBox for just displaying the data that you have within code some where within a List or Dictionary then yes very easily because you just check the List or Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You can create own subclass of QComboBox (and respectively QListWidget). 
Then you can create method `__contains__` and overload other method. Like in this example:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QComboBox, QApplication


class UniqueComboBox(QComboBox):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._current_values = set()

    def __contains__(self, item):
        return item in self._current_values

    def addItem(self, text):  # this is simple implementation. do not support all cases
        if text not in self._current_values:
            super().addItem(text)
            self._current_values.add(text)

    def addItems(self, text_list):
        for el in text_list:
            self.addItem(el)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    combo = UniqueComboBox()
    combo.addItems(["a", "b", "a", "c"])
    print("a" in combo, "z" in combo)
    combo.show()
    app.exec_()
```